# Why is this form in bakbone.js doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

Copied a part of a tutorial, but it doesn't functioning. Looked into the book - all seems quite right, but still doesn't work!
Router works fine, but the form doesn't...

```
var Start = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $('#start'), // DOM элемент widget'а
events: {
    "click input:button": "check" // Обработчик клика на кнопке "Проверить"
},
check: function () {
    alert('a');
    if (this.el.find("input:text").val() == "test") {// Проверка текста
        controller.navigate("success", true); // переход на страницу success
        alert('b');
    }
    else {
        controller.navigate("error", true); // переход на страницу error
        alert('c');
    }
}
});

var Controller = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    "": "start", // Пустой hash-тэг
    "!/": "start", // Начальная страница
    "!/success": "success", // Блок удачи
    "!/error": "error" // Блок ошибки
},

start: function () {
    $(".block").hide(); // Прячем все блоки
    $("#start").show(); // Показываем нужный
},

success: function () {
    $(".block").hide();
    $("#success").show();
},

error: function () {
    $(".block").hide();
    $("#error").show();
}
});
```

Comment: the code above is the definition of your view and router, but where are you instantiating them?

Comment: i do=) just didn't post those `var start = new Start(); var controller = new Controller();`

Comment: i can see `alert('a');` but non of others...

Comment: the alerts are below the navigate so you wont see them unless you move them before

Comment: i thought the same, commented the navigation - no difference. maybe the problem is with `this.el.find("input:text").val() == "test"`

Comment: Well try using $(this.el).find("input:text").val()